# How to change macOS Terminal.app settings programmatically?

Tags: mac, terminal, fonts, themes, applescript

My goal is to save the settings for my Terminal.app somewhere and then load them on a new installation or a different Mac. This should include at least the font size, font and the theme I'm using, even if it is a third party theme like [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). I don't want to perform any action for this other than running a script. This script could download the theme and font, of course, it doesn't have to package those in. I had a look at applescript but wasn't successfull.

Any ideas? Can I interact with the Terminal.app settings from the Terminal itself? Is the defaults tool something I should be looking into?

(Also: I'd like to do the same for iTerm2.)

Answer (score 0):

For Terminal you can export each profile from the Terminal Preferences... In the "Profiles" tab you can mark the profile you want to export and then click on the cogwheel at the bottom of the list of profiles and choose Export... (see figure)

[image: Terminal settings drop down menu]

This will save a "Profilename.terminal" file that you can open later to install that profile on the new machine with

```
open Profilename.terminal
```